# MySQL Update Multiple Columns with IF ELSE Statement in PHP in single Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySql Queries in PHP. I want to merge them ino one two reduce database load.

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE doorshippers_products 
        SET status='2', price='".$pp."', stock='0', timestemp='".$time."' 
        WHERE sku=$skuu AND price!=$pp";

$conn->query($sql1);


$sql2 = "UPDATE doorshippers_products 
        SET timestemp='".$time."' WHERE 
        sku=$skuu AND price=$pp";

$conn->query($sql2);
```

I want to merge them into one using if/else

Comment: Your queries are asking/answering two different questions. The ` AND price!=$pp` in particular at the end of the first one says "set status, price, and stock if the price isn't what is passed in", then the next query says "Set the timestamp where the price is equal to `$pp`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF` and set the column back to the same value in one condition, otherwise the new value.

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE doorshippers_products 
        SET status=IF(price = $pp, status, '2'), 
        price='".$pp."', 
        stock=IF(price = $pp, stock, '0'), 
        timestemp='".$time."' 
        WHERE sku=$skuu";
```

Comment: I agree that it's not beautiful, but it's better than many ternary expressions we've seen.

Comment: It's also vulnerable to sql injection